# Wildcard SSL certificate for a custom TLD?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ssl

I'm currently operating an intranet with a significant number of services, with each referred to by a domain with a custom TLD.

SearX --> search.companyname
Nextcloud --> files.companyname

As it stands, I have a custom CA installed on all clients using the intranet and have issued a certificate which covers each service.

I was wondering if it is possible to issue a certificate which is a wildcard for the entire tld? In other words, **a certificate for *.companyname**

I created such a certificate but firefox rejects it, saying

`Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for search.companyname. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.companyname`

I can imagine this may be a security measure, and would expect it for recognised TLDs, but I wondered if it also applies to custom TLDs?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *"I created such a certificate ...."* - how exactly? Make sure that the name is given as subject alternative name, not (only) as CN.

Comment: Don't invent TLDs, you will only get problems. Register one domain, in any TLD, and then use it as suffix of all internal naming needs.

Comment: No that is unlikely. However some authorities offer "private" certificate authority services for this. Some only have a full feature PKI solution that is managed or integrated into an existing environment. Others may issue a certificate as usual, but it is not from a public CA that is in a known trust chain. It's from a private CA that would need to be added to a trust list.